# subiquity mount second media in early commands

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, subiquity

I am recreating the *squashfs* image (Ubuntu Focal) and putting the `autoinstall` answers inside the `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_autoinstall.cfg` file of the squashed filesystem. I've got everything working fine so far.

Now I would like to mount a second USB drive at already the early stage, something like this:

```
early-commands:
    - mkdir -p /target/media/gse-archive
    - mount /dev/disk/by-label/U20ARCHIVE /target/media/gse-archive
```

But compared to the `late-commands` there is nothing like `/target`. So I wonder if this could be achieved somehow?

The final goal, is to put the whole Ubuntu Focal archive onto this USB drive, set the `sources.list` right and perform a local `dist-upgrade`.

Thx

Comment: Why does it need to be done so early? Going by the goal, shouldn't it be fine as a `late-command`?

Comment: Because the "packages" command is being executed before the late-commands.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty much straight forward.

In the early commands section:

```
  early-commands:
    - mkdir -p /media/gse-archive
    - mount -o rw,async,nodiratime $(readlink -f /dev/disk/by-label/U20ARCHIVE) /media/gse-archive
```

And if it is needed in the target:

```
  late-commands:
    - mount --rbind /media /target/media
```